# Are there any known conflicts between the official Samsung GpsRestore App for the Galaxy-S and custom roms?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, gps

Samsung have released an app for the Android Market in order to reset the GPS to factory settings, on Galaxy-S devices that experience problems using it. It should fix the GPS problems that a lot of people are experiencing.

([Android Spin: Samsung Finally Has a GPS Fix](http://androidspin.com/2010/12/01/samsung-finally-has-a-gps-fix/))

However, I know that several custom ROMs also attempt to fix the problematic Galaxy-S GPS. Does anyone know (or experienced) any problems after running that application on a custom ROM?

Comment: I think if you're using custom ROMs, you do not need to apply Samsung's fix.

Comment: Note that this fix is only for the US Captivate and Vibrant Galaxy S variants. Presumably Samsung are releasing this as a stop-gap until they (or the networks) get round to releasing 2.2 for those Galaxy S variants?

Comment: See also: [How can I fix my GPS?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/how-can-i-fix-the-gps-on-my-samsung-galaxy-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app only changes the settings, so it doesn't matter which GPS code the ROM has.  All the custom ROMs I know of use GPS code from Samsung anyways.

One note: This will fix **very few** people's problems.  The factory settings cause most of the problems, so restoring will probably hurt more than help.  It is possible that the new 2.2 releases will fix some issues, however, and in that case it's probably better to use whatever settings Samsung tested with the new GPS code, i.e. the settings GpsRestore uses.