# What can I do when my GPS doesn't work (or if my tablet doesn't have GPS)?

Tags: gps, navigation, network-signal

The problem: I want to use an (offline|online) navigation app but:

- I have an Asus Transformer Prime with very bad GPS reception
- I have a tablet without GPS (e.g., a Nook Color)
- My phone has a very low GPS signal
  (Samsung is infamous here, Galaxy S, Nexus S, Gio and so on all have users complaining about it)
- My phone often loses track of GPS satellites

My device has Bluetooth however.

What can I do to get a working and precise GPS signal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have several bluetooth-GPS adapters that I use with all of my devices when I need a superb signal because a specialiced receiver is almost always superior to a smartphone's internal GPS (due to integration constraints).

- **GPS Receiver**: My favourite is the [Bluemax 4043](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Blumax#GPS-4043) bluetooth receiver. It has more than one day uptime, it can also log 32MB of GPS data and uses a [cheap Nokia BL-5C battery](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=nokia%20bl-5c&_sacat=0). [Linux support](http://www.rigacci.org/wiki/doku.php/doc/appunti/hardware/gps_logger_i_blue_747)! OpenStreetMaps Wiki has a [comprehensive list](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/GPS_Reviews) of good receivers (search for the bluetooth enabled ones).
- **Software support**: Cyanogenmod7+ can [connect to GPS bluetooth receivers](http://iloki.nl/2012/01/29/external-bt-gps-merged-cm9-and-cm7-while-ago/), stock Android users may install 3rd party apps like [Bluetooth GPS Provider](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mobilej.btgps).

It's very handy for my Nook Color tablet that has no GPS but bluetooth (Asus Transformer Prime users also have this kind of problem).

Answer (score 1):

The Transformer Prime has a problem with its GPS all right. You can get a free external GPS adapter that fits into the docking port.

http://event.asus.com/ASUSPad/TF201GPS/