# Why GPS is never found?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, gps, odin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix the GPS on my Samsung Galaxy S?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/how-can-i-fix-the-gps-on-my-samsung-galaxy-s)

I've got a Samsung GT-I9000 (SGS1), it was on a pretty old stock firmware. I upgraded and rooted it with Odin and installed [CyanogenMod 9](http://download.cyanogenmod.com/?type=stable&device=galaxysmtd) and the [Icy-Glitch](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1459576) Kernel.

However I can't get any GPS signal, if I'm in Google Maps it keeps saying something like "Searching for GPS" (original on German "GPS wird gesucht").

I know that it did work with the old firmware when I got it.

What can I do to get the GPS back working?

Comment: Maybe a special CM issue. Many HTC-Buzz-Owners experienced this. Most got it fixed by (re-)flashing the radio. PS: @Flow I don't think its a duplicate, as the link you posted refers explicitly to Samsung firmware and a Samsung provided fix -- except if it does not refer to the system image (but e.g. the radio), which I could not figure out here.

Comment: @Izzy IMHO the famous SGS GPS problem is a pure hardware issue. Most fix attempts have to do with hardware and also [my answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/8489/440).

Comment: @Flow Thanks for clearification! Not having an SGS, I just barely remember there was an issue several years ago with SGS & GPS, but forgot all the details ;)

Comment: Well i know It worked For the old user of the phone (Stock). It didnt work on my old Rom either(Dark Knight 5.5).

Comment: @wayback if you are 100% sure that it worked on stock rom then it's most certainly a software issue which can be fixed by changing the rom or updating. But IIRC the GPS issues on the SGS where mostly caused by bad hardware design.

Comment: Are you indoors? Try going outside.