# aGPS on Xolo Q800(X-Edition) unable to find 'first-fix'

Tags: gps

Android Phones in question:

- [Xolo Q800](http://www.gsmarena.com/xolo_q800-5531.php)
- [Xolo Q800 X-Edition](http://www.gsmarena.com/xolo_q800_x_edition-5845.php)

I own X-Edition version & aGPS is unable to find first-fix since the '**day one**'. When on Google-maps, location defaults to tower(GSM mobile Transceiver, BTS) co-ordinates.

1. Installed `GPS Test` app, I noticed all packets received were portrayed as **gray bars** on the SNR graph of the utility.
2. Installed `GPS Status` app, reset GPS data/cache & downloaded it afresh. Still first-fix was nowhere in sight.
3. Checked Xolo website for s/w upgrade, although there is an update to 4.2 most Xolo-Q800 are complaining about buggy update on various forums. I'm reluctant to upgrade or try out custom ROMs.
4. Came across this [Fixing the GPS on my Samsung Galaxy S?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/how-can-i-fix-the-gps-on-my-samsung-galaxy-s). The procedure is totally different & aGPS is a solution over here.

I found `agps_profiles_conf.xml` file at location `/system/etc/`. It's full of aGPS server details.

Can this be addressed? Please push me in right direction to fix this glitch.

PS: I also own Sony Xperia SP, GLONASS works flawlessly on it.

file `agps_profiles_conf.xml` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<agps_profiles version="1">

    <!--  slp_name: default slp name to be shown in AGPS
    backup_slp_name_var: mui slp name variable in string.xml(optional) 
    address: SLP address
    show_type: whether show this profile or not, 0:always show  1:only show in engineer mode  2:show according to current operator
   -->

    <!-- Spirent Lab -->
    <agps_profile code=""
      slp_name="Lab - Spirent"
      backup_slp_name_var="Spirent"
      address="www.spirent-lcs.com"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="1"
  />

    <!-- R&S Lab -->
    <agps_profile code=""
      slp_name="Lab - RnS"
      backup_slp_name_var="RS"
      address="slp.rs.de"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="1"
  />

    <!-- CMCC Lab -->
    <agps_profile code=""
      slp_name="Lab - CMCC"
      backup_slp_name_var="CMCC"
      address="218.206.176.50"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="1"
  />

    <!-- Andrew Lab -->
    <agps_profile code=""
      slp_name="Lab - Andrew"
      backup_slp_name_var="Andrew"
      address="slp1acva.andrew.com"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="1"
  />

    <!-- Ericsson  Lab -->
    <agps_profile code=""
      slp_name="Lab - Ericsson"
      backup_slp_name_var="Ericsson"
      address="172.22.1.100"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="1"
  />



    <!-- NOKIA-->
    <agps_profile code="NOKIA"
      slp_name="NOKIA"
      backup_slp_name_var="NOKIA_SPL_Name"
      address="supl.nokia.com"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="0"
  />

    <!-- GOOGLE-->
    <agps_profile code="GOOGLE"
      slp_name="GOOGLE"
      backup_slp_name_var="GOOGLE_SPL_Name"
      address="supl.google.com"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="0"
  />

    <!-- ORANGE 00-->
    <agps_profile code="20800"
      slp_name="ORANGE 00"
      backup_slp_name_var="ORANGE00_SPL_Name"
      address="agpss.orange.fr"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="2"
  />
    <!-- ORANGE 01-->
    <agps_profile code="20801"
      slp_name="ORANGE 01"
      backup_slp_name_var="ORANGE01_SPL_Name"
      address="agpss.orange.fr"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="2"
  />
    <!-- ORANGE 02-->
    <agps_profile code="20802"
      slp_name="ORANGE 02"
      backup_slp_name_var="ORANGE02_SPL_Name"
      address="agpss.orange.fr"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="2"
  />

    <!-- CMCC-->
    <agps_profile code="46000"
      slp_name="China Mobile AGPS server"
      backup_slp_name_var="CMCC_SPL_Name"
      address="221.176.0.55"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="2"
      app_id="ap0004"
      provider_id="221.176.0.55"
      default_apn="CMCC WAP"
      optional_apn="CMNET"
      optional_apn_2=""
      address_type="IPv4address:port"
  />

    <!-- CMCC2-->
    <agps_profile code="46002"
      slp_name="China Mobile AGPS server"
      backup_slp_name_var="CMCC_SPL_Name"
      address="221.176.0.55"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="2"
      app_id="ap0004"
      provider_id="221.176.0.55"
      default_apn="CMCC WAP"
      optional_apn="CMNET"
      optional_apn_2=""
      address_type="IPv4address:port"
  />

    <!-- CMCC TD-->
    <agps_profile code="46007"
      slp_name="China Mobile AGPS server"
      backup_slp_name_var="CMCC_SPL_Name"
      address="221.176.0.55"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="2"
      app_id="ap0004"
      provider_id="221.176.0.55"
      default_apn="CMCC WAP"
      optional_apn="CMNET"
      optional_apn_2=""
      address_type="IPv4address:port"
  />

    <!-- Telstra-->
    <agps_profile code="Telstra"
      slp_name="Telstra"
      backup_slp_name_var="Telstra_SPL_Name"
      address="agps.supl.telstra.com"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="1"
  />

    <!-- Vodafone
  <agps_profile code="Vodafone"
      slp_name="Vodafone"
      backup_slp_name_var="Vodafone_SPL_Name"
      address="supl.vodafone.com"
      port="7275"
      tls="1"
      show_type="0"
      mcc_mnc="22010"
  />
  -->

    <!-- CHUAN HWA
  <agps_profile code="46692"
      slp_name="Chunghwa"
      backup_slp_name_var="CHUANHWA_SPL_Name"
      address="10.1.101.137"
      port="8025"
      tls="0"
      show_type="2"
  />
    -->

    <!-- China Unicom Test 
  <agps_profile code="46001"
      slp_name="China Unicom"
      backup_slp_name_var="CU_SPL_Name"
      address="172.0.0.1"
      port="8025"
      tls="0"
      show_type="2"
  />
  -->

    <!-- Profile for CDMA-->
    <cdma_profile name="CDMA1"
    mcp_enable="no"
    mcp_addr="10.199.2.165"
    mcp_port="6066"
    pde_addr_valid="no"
    pde_ip_type="0"
    pde_ip4_addr="11.11.11.11"
    pde_ip6_addr="001.002.003.004.005.006.007.008.009.010.011.012.013.014.015.016"
    pde_port="1111"
    pde_url_valid="no"
    pde_url_addr="www.mediatek.com"
  />

    <cdma_profile name="CDMA2"
    mcp_enable="no"
    mcp_addr="2.2.2.2"
    mcp_port="222"
    pde_addr_valid="no"
    pde_ip_type="1"
    pde_ip4_addr="22.22.22.22"
    pde_ip6_addr="001.002.003.004.005.006.007.008.009.010.011.012.013.014.015.116"
    pde_port="2222"
    pde_url_valid="no"
    pde_url_addr="www.mediatek.com2"
  />

    <cdma_profile name="CDMA3"
    mcp_enable="no"
    mcp_addr="3.3.3.3"
    mcp_port="333"
    pde_addr_valid="yes"
    pde_ip_type="1"
    pde_ip4_addr="33.33.33.33"
    pde_ip6_addr="001.002.003.004.005.006.007.008.009.010.011.012.013.014.015.226"
    pde_port="3333"
    pde_url_valid="no"
    pde_url_addr="www.mediatek.com3"
  />

    <!-- The following parameters are provided for customer to 
    configure A-GPS default value.
-->
    <!--  
   agps_enable:(for CP/UP)
      whether to permit enable A-GPS when the first boot up.
      Available value: yes, no (case sensitive)

   ca_enable: (for UP only)
      enable or disable  the certification
      Available value: yes, no (case sensitive)

   cdma_agps_preferred: (for CDMA only)
      when CDMA network and WCDMA network are available, which AGPS protocol you prefer?
      Avaialbe value: 0 (WCDMA AGPS protocol is preferred)
      Avaialbe value: 1 (CDMA AGPS protocol is preferred)
      Avaialbe value: 2 (FORCE CDMA AGPS protocol)

   cp_auto_reset: (for CP only)
     enable or disable PMTK997_5 for CP reset flow
     Available value: yes, no (case sensitive)

   cp_gemini_pref_sim: (for CP only)
      This parameter indicates which SIM you want to use for CP MO-LR and 
    it is used only when two available SIMs are ready.
      Available value: 1 (it means use sim1 as prefrerred) 
      Available value: 2 (it means use sim2 as prefrerred if your platform supports two or more SIM)
      Available value: 3 (it means use sim3 as prefrerred if your platform supports three or more SIM)
      Available value: 4 (it means use sim4 as prefrerred if your platform supports four or more SIM)

   cp_up_selection: (for CP/UP)
      choose which agps protocol (CP/UP) you want to use for SI case if UP selected or MOLR case if CP selected
      Available value: cp (Control Plane is used for MOLR, case sensitive)
      Available value: up (User Plane is used for SI, case sensitive)

   default_cdma_profile: (for CDMA only)
      the default CDMA profile when device first boot up, please assign the name in cdma_profile name
      Available value: CDMA1

   default_profile:(for UP only)
      the default profile when device first boot up. please assign the slp_name 
      Available value: NOKIA, GOOGLE 

   disable_after_reboot:(for CP/UP)
      whether to enable A-GPS when device sencond boot up.
      Available value: yes, no (case sensitive)

   ecid_enable: (for UP only)
      enable or disable eCID functionality for UP
      Available value: yes, no (case sensitive)

   gpevt: (for CP/UP)
     enable or disable the GPEVT message forwarding functionality from AGPSD to MNL
     Available value: yes, no (case sensitive)

   log_file_max_num: (for UP only)
      the max number of log file can be saved in /data/agps_supl/log.
      Available vaule: 1~100

   ni_request:(for CP/UP)
      whether to accept the network request for SET's location 
      Available value: yes, no (case sensitive)

   notify_timeout: (for UP only)
      determine how long does A-GPS Dialog for notification type need to show
      Available value: 0~20

   roaming: (for UP only)
      whether to use A-GPS when device is under roaming
      Available value: yes, no (case sensitive)

   si_mode:(for UP only)
      set si mode to ma or mb
      Available value: ma, mb (case sensitive)

   supl_version: (for UP only)
     choose which SUPL version you want to use
     Available value: 1, 2

   verify_timeout: (for UP only)
      determine how long does A-GPS Dialog for verification type need to show
      Available value: 0~20     
  -->
    <agps_conf_para
    agps_enable="no"
    ca_enable="no"
    cdma_agps_preferred="0"
    cp_auto_reset="no"
    cp_gemini_pref_sim="1"
    cp_up_selection="up"
    default_cdma_profile="CDMA1"
    default_profile="GOOGLE"
    disable_after_reboot="no"
    ecid_enable="yes"
    gpevt="no"
    log_file_max_num="10"
    ni_request="no"
    notify_timeout="8"
    roaming="no"
    si_mode="mb"
    supl_version="1"
    verify_timeout="8"
  />
</agps_profiles>
```

I see default points to `GOOGLE`, `supl.google.com:7275`. Will changing port to `7276` has any significance?

Comment: Are you rooted? If not, you will definitely need root to modify `/system/etc/agps_profiles_conf.xml`.

Comment: How to verify it? I've Anti Theft app installed by default, to erase/reset remotely if need arises.

Comment: Eh? I asked you if you were rooted.

Comment: @t0mm13b I don't have root access. Working on rooting my `Xolo-Q800X`